# Question on updating packages using Ansible

Tags: ansible

My Ansible playbook contains packages that I want to install with the latest versions; however, it does not occur. I understand with `apt` you won't get the latest updates but what would be the best approach in Ansible to update the latest packages?

setup.yml

```
sys_packages: [ 'curl', 'vim', 'git', 'ufw', 'wget', 'aptitude', 'ca-certificates', 'software-properties-common', 'gnupg-agent', 'vagrant', 'ansible', 'python3-pip', 'apt-transport-https', 'virtualenv', 'bash', 'nodejs', 'npm', 'ntp', 'ntpdate', 'htop' ]
```

playbook.yml

```
### Complete setup of packages for Debian/Ubuntu distros
- name: Update and install all required system packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ sys_packages }}"
      state: latest
      update_cache: yes
```

The distro I want to install the Ansible script is on Ubuntu versions.

UPDATE: Dec. 19, 2020
This is dumb of me. I have been researching and found if one can use the `curl` command in Ansible or create a custom PPA repository, then you can get the current version of each of these packages that you would need since any distro package maintainer (with any version) will be different when using `apt-get` (e.g. using `apt-get virtualbox` in 18.04 and 20.04 will provide different versions). I will update my post once I can complete my objective.

Comment: What you have should in theory work -- since you're setting the `state` to `latest` and you're also updating the cache. Are you getting any errors when you run it? How much older are the packages than you expect them to be? Does it work on your target host(s) if you try manually via `apt-get` on the host itself? Maybe try setting `update_cache_retries` to a higher value, say 10 (the default is 5) and see if that helps.

Comment: @costaparas thank you for your reply costa. I am able to process each package successfully with no errors. Let's take for instance Ubuntu 18.04 that I test. When I run the Ansible script with module `apt` for Ubuntu 18.04, I receive `git` as 2.17.1 when it should be 2.29.2, and vagrant being 2.0.2 when it should be 2.2.14. I will look into manually using `apt-get` to see if there would be a difference as well as `update_cache_retries`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully update my packages with the latest updates for certain packages I wanted such as ansible, git, and vagrant. Here is how the code looks:

```
###### PPA Repository Setup
###### Add a complete set of repositories into the source list to be updated to the latest version.
###### The only repositories that are up to date are git, ansible, and vagrant. The others will have to be
###### installed separately.
    - name: Add stable repositories from PPA to system
      apt_repository:
          repo: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ppa:ansible/ansible                     # Latest Ansible repo
        - ppa:git-core/ppa                        # Latest git repo
        - ppa:tiagohillebrandt/vagrant            # Latest Vagrant repo (this is a personal ppa so this needs to be wary)
```

And let's say you want to add the GPG keys for different repositories such as Docker, here is an example:

```
###### Docker Setup
###### Setup Docker's GPG key and Docker's repository. It is recommended prior to installation to have
###### these apps installed: apt-transport-https, ca-certificates, curl, gnupg-agent, and software-properties-common.
    - name: Add Docker GPG apt key
      apt_key:
        url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
        state: present

    - name: Add Docker Repository
      apt_repository:
          repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable
          state: present
```

Now the repo named `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable` is something I need to work on. If the version of your Ubuntu let's say 18.04. You would replace `$(lsb_release -cs)` with `bionic`. However, `lsb_release` should provide the version. Thanks for the help all and I hope this helps anyone out there